# Follow a question by notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, notifications

When an interesting question is asked on Stack Overflow, I would like the option to follow any answers via notification whenever there are new answers and/or comments.

Marking a question as a favorite is different than "following", and does not notify about new answers and comments.

Is there any possibility that Stack Overflow could implement this?

See the example image below.

[image: Image showing a question with possible 'follow' button highlighted.]

Comment: It would be nice to get notification from - or also from - favorite questions too.

Comment: *"favoriting a question does not notify me about new answers"* - not in the top bar, but there is an activity count on the favorites tab.

Comment: 5 years passed and still no answer from the stackoverflow staff.

Comment: It appears to now be actioned: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/284827

Comment: `status-completed`?

Comment: Ten times. Ten time today so far I've gone to click the edit link only to click the share link because of the addition of the new follow link. Please move the follow link to the end of the list of existing links, after flag.

Comment: @j08691 Noooo...!! Please don't move it to the end! Everyone that flags all the time will hit the follow instead. Move it in between the `edit` and the (`close`) `flag` links.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the bottom of every question is a link to the question feed.

[image: Question Feed]

You can utilize this, and a feed parser of your choice, to follow any questions you wish.

Comment: That's not always true; consider questions which are downvoted or closed.  (A quick test shows that the link doesn't appear for the former.)  Besides, what if you want to follow a question anyway?  How does this feature help with that?

Comment: @Makoto: This also doesn't provide *comment* entries.

Answer (score 2):

Overjoyed  to see follow feature now without any funky hacks. See at *bottom left of screenshot* -- "share, edit, **follow**, flag"

[image: shr]

This little feature makes using stackoverflow such a delight. Thanks to engineers at stackoverflow

Sample notification at inbox
[image]